# Elementos amontonados Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

estoy empezando en Android Studio (2.3), hice un programa con 4 elementos (suma de números) pero a la hora de ejecutarlo los elementos aparecen encimados en la parte superior izquierda y no puedo manipular el programa, a que se deberá?

Gracias

Comment: Tu pregunta no deja muy claro que es tu problema (tengo la sospecha que es un problema de layout). podrías quizás proveer un poco de código de lo que haces, lo que esperas como resultado y que exactamente no te funciona?

Comment: agrega almenos el código del layout.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes habilitado el soporte para [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html), y estas usando como layout principal un [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html), tus vistas se están mostrando en las coordenadas 0,0 seguramente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Define restricciones en tus vistas para que aparezcan en posición correcta cuando se ejecute tu aplicación**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encontré un tutorial en español, pero agrego el de la documentación:

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

---

Si no deseas usar `ConstraintLayout`, simplemente cambia en tu layout .xml, de :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

a otro tipo de layout por ejemplo `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
```

o `RelativeLayout`:

```
   <RelativeLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando estas creando aplicaciones en android studio, las ultimas versiones vienen con esta opcion por defecto para interfaces responsive con android:

> android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

el cual lo puedes borrar del xml del layout ademas de quitarlo del gradle.

Entonces en el XML lo cambias por:

> RelativeLayout

desde allí, puedes ubicar tu vista en cualquier parte del RelativeLayout
empleando

> android:layout_alignParentTop, 
>   android:layout_centerVertical, entre otras opciones

o si lo quieres ademas colocar al lado de otra vista puedes tambien agregar

> android:layout_toRightOf y otros por el estilo

aqui te dejo de los desarrolladores de android todo al respecto.
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Answer (score 0):

A mí me salía el mismo error y era por una dependencia en el archivo

**AppAndroid\app\build.gradle**

cambié el

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
```

por

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```