# Problema con el emulador y el diseño?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, programación-móvil, diseño

Por qué cuando trato de ver la App en el emulador salen todos los elementos desorganizados y en el área de diseño todo esta bien?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo mas probable es que no estés usando la constraint layout de manera correcta,  y que por eso los elementos se vayan de su lugar. Trata de usar los constraints correctamente y debería de quedar justamente donde quieres! Si es posible actualiza la pregunta con una foto del layout y podre ayudarte mas. Saludos!

Comment: gracias si era la parte del constraint layout

Comment: @larry agrega las guías para que tus elementos no se muevan cuando se muestre en el emulador o tu dispositivo. Revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/57616/elementos-amontonados-android-studio/57785#57785